# Upgrading Jboss application server 4.1.1 to Latest Versions

Tags: jboss, upgrade

I am very new to jboss app server and using jboss app server 4.1.4 and want to upgrade to any latest version like 6 or 7. What’s the best process to perform i.e. I have seen that “copy the .rar and .war files” and these can’t make right scene to work. What's the best process?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to start is to get an overview over your existing application. In particular:

- Which non-standard JBoss features do you use (JBoss Cache, JCA Work Manager, …)?
- What "managed resources" (data sources, connection factories, …) do you use?
- Which configuration changes did you make (connection pool, transaction timeout, …)?
- Which classloading assumptions does your packaging make?

and then individually check how these are handled in the JBoss version you want to migrate to.

Comment: is i have to go for SAS 9.2 for migration to latest version? or can i install any patch like CSP patch feed to get latest version and how? let me know the way step by step ..

Comment: Check the documentation of SAS to find out what version they support. I don't think there is a patch for upgrading JBoss.

Comment: so in what way can i expect the upgradation...?

Comment: As I said, you'd have to post the result of the analysis of the points I described for me to be able to give you an answer.

Answer (score -1):

there is no one to answer this question..looks shame about it.